# Meta refresh tag adds semicolons to URL (;)

Tags: php, forms, refresh, meta

I have a PHP/HTML form that when the submit form button is pressed it is supposed make the database changes and redirect the page to another URL to view the form details. The next page requires receiving two variables via GET in order to load the information from the database.

I am using the following line of code to redirect the page after the form is submitted:

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" Content="0;URL=http://grserviceswap.isys489.com/dev/Abraham/providerViewsAPost.php?SPPostingID=' . $PostingID . '&UserID=' . $UserID . '"/>';
```

The problem is that when it redirects it adds two semicolons like this:

```
http://grserviceswap.isys489.com/dev/Abraham/providerViewsAPost.php?SPPostingID=7;%20&UserID=33;
```

The semicolon add the end prevents the page from loading properly. I can remove it manually and it will work, but normal users won't know to do that.

How can I get the meta refresh to not add the semicolons?

Comment: Attributes in header fields should be quoted, as in `0; URL='http://'`

Comment: @mario, content is the attribute, not URL in meta.

Comment: @Devon The prescribed [HTTP header field value encoding](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#page-27) still applies in the context of HTML meta tags. (Still relevant even if OP had garbage input vars.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sanitizing GET variables to protect against XSS (cross site scripting) attacks.  If both are integers, you can enforce that.

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" Content="0;URL=http://grserviceswap.isys489.com/dev/Abraham/providerViewsAPost.php?SPPostingID=' . intval($PostingID) . '&amp;UserID=' . intval($UserID) . '"/>';
```

Note I also changed the & to `&amp;` which is the correct HTML encoding.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I did not know about sanitizing GET variables.

Comment: You should research cross site scripting then.  If any output (HTML) contains a $_GET value, you should be sanitizing it to protect users from Javascript injections.  Please mark this as resolved since this fixed your problem.

Comment: Ok, I will look in to that. Thank you so much!